# Error in console using ngRepeat in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-ng-repeat, src

I am a new person to AngularJS and I've got a little problem.

Here is my code:

JS:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('appList', []);

app.controller('AppListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.url = 'getappinfo.php';
    $http.post($scope.url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.apps = data;
    }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data, status);
        });
})

app.directive('application', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name: "@",
            logo: "@"
        },
        template: "<div style='width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid black'>{{name}}     <img src='{{logo}}' style='width:50px'></div>"
    }
})
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="appList">
   <div ng-controller="AppListCtrl" id='applications_holder'>
       <div ng-repeat="app in apps">
        <application name="{{app.name}}" logo="{{app.logo}}"></application>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

From getappinfo.php I get a json array with several objects in it...All of them have 'name' and 'logo' properties. It all works fine.

But still I have a little problem that bothers me:
[image: Eror in console]

This is an error that I get in console of Google Chrome.

I understand the cause of this error. But I don't know how to get rid of it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [ngSrc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc) to prevent the browser from requesting a file called "{{logo}}", which gets rendered before your scope has been bound to your view.

Broken: http://jsfiddle.net/wNwrr/

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/wNwrr/1

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="x">
    <img ng-src="{{src}}" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function x($scope) {
    $scope.src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png';
}
```